# Why is navigator object empty in my phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigator, phonegap

Having issues with my app that have been taking up the last 24 hours of my life. I've drilled it down to the fact that the "navigator" object is completely empty.

It's not empty on my phonegap developer test app, however as soon as I build the app and deploy onto a test device - the app suddenly cannot read the navigator object... I checked and it's completely empty.

Why would this be the case, that only once built and deployed is the navigator object completely empty?

Comment: The `navigator` in this context is your browser => app -vs- browser ???

Comment: `navigator` is not a standardized object. Even when it is present, the information you can extract from it is highly unreliable. There's no real practical reason to use it for most applications. What data are you trying to get?

Comment: Scott Marcus using it to grab geolocation as well as do a notification via phonegaps navigator.

Comment: sounds like you trying to get the navigator object before "deviceready"  event, can you show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - I made a rookie mistake. I didn't know that the navigator object does not automatically work in a phonegap app, you have to install various plugins for the object such as the device plugin, geolocation plugin, etc.

Usually on mobile devices w/ internet browsers, this object is readily available. Even worse, this object IS readily available when testing the app in phonegap developer. But, once you build and deploy, it will not work without the proper plugins.

Comment: I have same problem. Could you please name the plugin I need to install to get `navigator.app` ?

Comment: @Dilawar It's all available on https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/ you need the geolocation plugin, ensure it is installed properly, and follow the proper methods for invoking it.